# The Lebesgue measure of the boundary of a simply connected domain

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Is the Lebesgue measure of the boundary of a simply connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ necessarily 0?

Acturally, I want to know the sufficient condition to guarantee the measure of the boundary of a domain is $0$.

Comment: might be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421934/set-e-subset-mathbbrn-of-positive-lebesgue-measure-such-that-the-lebesgue?rq=1

Answer (score 8):

Take a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), $C\subset \mathbb{R}$, i.e. a closed set with empty interior and nonzero measure.  Then consider the set $$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y <0\} \cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y\geq 0, x \notin C\}.$$

This set seems open, simply connected and with boundary $C \times [0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3):

Tim kinsella's answer is really fine, here is another suggestion (way more complicated).

Just take an [Osgood curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve) (*= Jordan arc of positive area*)

- This is an arc (continuous image of $[0,1]$ into the plane) therefore **simply connected**, and **closed**.
- It is also a **non self intersecting curve** (an arc is the image of an injective function), so it has **empty interior** (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43096/is-it-true-that-a-space-filling-curve-cannot-be-injective-everywhere) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254577/image-of-continuous-injective-map-has-empty-interior), the proof is easy)
- Thus the boundary of the Osgood curve is the curve itself, so it has positive measure.

---

See for instance [this step by step construction of an Osgood curve](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/KnoppsOsgoodCurveConstruction/) (by Knopp, on Wolfram Demonstrations).